# set file into dataframe by loop

Tags: python, loops

I want to set each file into a different DataFrame through a loop. Is there any way? I have a lot of files, which may be added in the future, so I want to simplify the process. the code as below is not work.

```
OUT_FILE=[a,b]
file_num=0
    for file in filelist:
        file= pd.read_excel(inPath+"xxx.xlsx", OUT_FILE[file_num], 0, dtype=('object'))
        file_num=file_num + 1
```

[current status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgaLc.png)

Comment: Create a list before the loop and append each file as DataFrame to it.

Comment: I want the different file into different dataframe.

Comment: I know. Each file as DataFrame would be an element of that list. So if you have 5 files you get a list of 5 elements where each is a DataFrame.

Comment: I tried, but after the loop, the element is empty. I don't know what happened. 
`filelist = [PTH_SCR, VTP_SCR, VCP_SCR, CUF_SCR,FIL_SCR,SOD_SCR,ODF1_SCR,ODF2_SCR,LT]
dflist = [PTH, VTP, VCP, CUF,FIL,SOD,ODF1,ODF2]
OUT_FILE = ['PTH', 'VTP', 'VCP', 'CUF','FIL','SOD','ODF1','ODF2','LT']
file_num=0
for file in filelist:
    file= pd.read_excel(inPath+"Dept. Code for PTH.xlsx", OUT_FILE[file_num], 0, dtype=('object'))
    file.append(file)
    file_num=file_num + 1`

Comment: Can you print your variables? What is in `filelist`? What are `a` and `b`? What is `inPath`? This code is not reproducible as it is. Please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Filelist is an element list, inpath is a file path. The whole code as below:
`filelist = [PTH_SCR, VTP_SCR, VCP_SCR, CUF_SCR,FIL_SCR,SOD_SCR,ODF1_SCR,ODF2_SCR,LT] dflist = [PTH, VTP, VCP, CUF,FIL,SOD,ODF1,ODF2] OUT_FILE = ['PTH', 'VTP', 'VCP', 'CUF','FIL','SOD','ODF1','ODF2','LT'] 
file_num=0 
for file in filelist:     
    file= pd.read_excel(inPath+"Dept. Code for PTH.xlsx", OUT_FILE[file_num], 0, dtype=('object'))     
    file.append(file)     
    file_num=file_num + 1`

Comment: You are using the variable name `file` for the list and for the DataFrame. I suggest naming the objects as follows: `list_of_dataframes` which holds the DataFrames, `file_df` instead of `file` in your `for`-loop (because `file` is a builin function and you're overwriting it).

Comment: Yes, thank you. You pointed out my mistake. I should use the method as below:
`for i in range(len(filelist)):
     filelist[i]=xxx`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).